# how select with json

Tags: php, mysql, select

```
<?php

    require("config.inc.php");

    if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM chatt
              WHERE 
       fromm= :username  AND chatt.too IN
       (SELECT friend2 FROM friends where friend1=:username)
       ";

        $query_params = array(
            ':username' => $_POST['username'],

        );


    try {
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();


    if ($rows) {
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Post Available!";
        $response["posts"]   = array();

        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $post             = array();


       $post["Message"]  = $row["message"];
            array_push($response["posts"], $post);
        }

        echo json_encode($response);


    } else {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No Post Available!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }

    } else {
    ?>
            <h1>Login</h1> 
            <form action="selectchat.php" method="post"> 
                Username:<br /> 
                <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" /> 
                <br /><br /> 


                <input type="submit" value="Login" /> 
            </form> 
            <a href="register.php">Register</a>
        <?php
    }

    ?>
```

the above code gives me this result:

```
{"success":1,"message":"Post Available!",
 "posts":[
  {"to":"ezenwa","Message":"this is me yes","time":"2015-02-08 23:47:31"},
  {"to":"mark","Message":"ok i can see","time":"2015-02-08 23:47:31"},
  {"to":"ezenwa","Message":"seems good","time":"2015-02-12 17:44:10"},
  {"to":"john","Message":"j nman ","time":"2015-02-13 14:42:16"},
  {"to":"david","Message":"j nman ","time":"2015-02-13 14:43:28"},
  {"to":"john","Message":"this is cool","time":"2015-02-13 14:58:28"}
]}
```

but I want the it to display only the last message between the user and each person on his list like…

**Edit**: update the json format.

```
{"success":1,
 "message":"Post Available!",
 "posts":[
  {"to":"mark","Message":"ok i can see","time":"2015-02-08 23:47:31"},
  {"to":"ezenwa","Message":"seems good","time":"2015-02-12 17:44:10"},
  {"to":"david","Message":"j nman ","time":"2015-02-13 14:43:28"},
  {"to":"john","Message":"this is cool","time":"2015-02-13 14:58:28"}
]}
```

if i am doing it the wrong way tell me..or if you have a better way please assit me

Comment: Using `MAX(time)` and `GROUP BY to` should be enough for your purposes. Something like `SELECT *, MAX(time) FROM chatt WHERE fromm = :username AND chatt.to IN (SELECT friend2 FROM friends WHERE friend1=:username) GROUP BY chatt.to ORDER BY chatt.time ASC`

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not getting your requirement wrongly, you just want to get latest message from Database.

You can `Order By timestamp` whatever column in your database chat table, rows coming from database by timestamp for chat table.

E.g

`Select * from chatt where .... order by timestamp DESC`

If i'm still missing your requirement let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I would parse array in PHP rather at client's side (javascript)

```
foreach($response['posts'] as $user){
$users[$user][] = array('message'=>$user['message'],'time'=>$user['time'])}
```

**then**  `usort($users, function($a,$b){return $a['time'] - $b['time']});`  **sort and grab the last ones**  `foreach($user as $k => $u){$res[] = array(strval($k) = > end($u))}`

---

```
 [..]} else {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No Post Available!";
```

$res = functions stated above($response)..

```
    die(json_encode($res));
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

I have no your data to debug, but you can

try this way:

```
    "SELECT chatt.`to`,chatt.`message`,c2.`time` FROM chatt

RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT `to`, MAX(`time`) as time 
    FROM chatt as c2 
    WHERE 
       `fromm`= :username  AND c2.too IN
       (SELECT friend2 FROM friends WHERE `friend1`= :username) 
    GORUP BY `to`) as c2
ON chatt.`to`=c2.`to` AND chatt.`time`=c2.`time`
    ";
```